# How to prevent ListTile results from repeating?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to display a list of girls who exist within a distance specified by a slider.

**Relevant Code:**

*girls.dart*

```
class Girls {
  String name;
  int distance;

  Girls(this.name, this.distance);
}
```

*girls_screen.dart*

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:switch_circle_color/model/girls.dart';

class GirlsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  GirlsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<GirlsScreen> createState() => _GirlsScreenState();
}

class _GirlsScreenState extends State<GirlsScreen> {
  int distance = 15;

  void changeDistance(double num) {
    setState(() {
      distance = num.round();

      populateFilteredGirls(distance);
      this.filteredGirls = filteredGirls;
    });
  }

  List<Girls> allGirls = [
    Girls("Reshmita", 25),
    Girls("Ankita", 17),
    Girls("Rupali", 42),
    Girls("Monica", 50),
    Girls("Sakshi", 9)
  ];

  List<Girls> filteredGirls = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //filteredGirls = allGirls;
    distance = 20;
    allGirls.sort((a, b) => a.distance.compareTo(b.distance));
    populateFilteredGirls(distance);
  }

  void populateFilteredGirls(int dis) {
    for (int i = 0; i < allGirls.length; i++) {
      if (allGirls[i].distance <= dis) {
        filteredGirls.add(allGirls[i]);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(20)),
          Slider(
            min: 1.0,
            max: 100.0,
            divisions: 100,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
            inactiveColor: Colors.orange,
            label: 'Set distance value',
            value: distance.toDouble(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              changeDistance(value);
            },
          ),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Text("Current distance is $distance kms"),
          Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.all(10)),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: filteredGirls.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(Icons.girl_outlined),
                  trailing: Text("${filteredGirls[index].distance} km away"),
                  title: Text("${filteredGirls[index].name}"),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

**Issue faced**:

When the app loads, I see the two girls who exist within the initially specified distance of 20 km.

[image]

However, when I drag the slider, to say, 30 km, the search result with 3 girls repeats after the initial search result of 2 girls.

[image]

How do I make sure that upon dragging the slider, only the new search result gets displayed and all previous search results disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear the list before adding items.

```dart
void populateFilteredGirls(int dis) {
  filteredGirls.clear();
  for (int i = 0; i < allGirls.length; i++) {
    if (allGirls[i].distance <= dis) {
      filteredGirls.add(allGirls[i]);
    }
  }
}
```